# Anaconda 2020.07 Matplotlib not updating

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda, conda

I just updated my Anaconda (to 2020.07) and Spyder (to 4.1.4)installations.  However, the Matplotlib package shows up as version 3.3.0 using pip list and 3.2.2 using conda list commands. Which is correct?  Also, how can I install the latest version of Matplotlib package?
I followed the following to update my Anaconda and spyder with the hope that it will upgrade all packages including Matplotlib,

```
conda install conda        
conda install anaconda        
conda install spyder
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have both a version of matploblib installed through pip and one installed through Conda in the same environment? We need some more context for this.

Comment: matplotlib 3.3.1 just released. When using conda, update with `conda update --all` at the conda prompt and do not update your conda packages with pip.

Comment: Yes, it looked like I had Matplotlib installed through pip as well.  I uninstalled the version installed through pip via pip uninstall matplotlib and now it shows the latest version of Matplotlib even with pip list command. Thanks for the inputs.